# Linking elements of a list as a tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python list that looks like this for example :

```
[Product(parent=tube,child=spokes), Product(parent=bicycle, child=wheel), Product(parent=wheel,child=tube)]
```

Where `Product` is a python class with two members `parent` and `child`.

The `Products` could appear in any order in the list.

What would be the most efficient `one liner` to achieve the following :

```
Given an input spokes for example , return the `root of the tree` , bicycle in this case.
```

What have i tried so far : inefficient for loops that does not give the right results when the Product does not appear in the same order each time.

Comment: Why do you need a one-liner? Do you have a multi-line solution already? What did you struggle with when creating your "inefficient for loops" solution?

Comment: (_making a Jedi gesture_) one-liners need you not. Build a child-to-parent dictionary, then look it up recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pseudo code for your problem :

```
def recursiveRootFinder(child,theList):
    for(i in theList):
        if (i.child==child):
            child=recursiveRootFinder(i.parent,theList)
    return child
```

You can use lambda definition to implement it in one line like that :

```
lambda child,theList: recursiveRootFinder(i.parent,theList) for i in list if i.child==child if [1 for i in list if i.child==child]!=[] else child
```

Comment: Your solution is quadratic.

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota I  can't comment below your answer, but your solution is not quiet exactly what was asked. The aim of the program is to find the root from a list AND a child (meaning there might be more than one root). But yes, your solution is in O(nln(n)) and it is easy to fix it to match with the requirement.

Comment: I approved your edit. The dict in python is implemented as hashmap, so in optimistic case (no hash collision) the solution is linear.

Answer (score 2):

You do not write how strong assumption you can apply to data (if it is always proper tree). So my code check some conditions to not stick in infinity loop.

```py
def find_root(pr_list, child):
    if len(pr_list) == 0:
        return None
    child_translate_dict = {x.child: x for x in pr_list}
    potential_root = child
    count = 0
    while count < len(pr_list):
        if potential_root not in child_translate_dict:
            return potential_root
        else:
            potential_root = child_translate_dict[potential_root].parent
            count += 1 
    return None
```

and shorter version

```py
def find_root(pr_list, child):
    child_translate_dict = {x.child: x for x in pr_list}
    while child in child_translate_dict:
        child = child_translate_dict[potential_root].parent
    return child
```